# Show function has no extremum

Tags: multivariable-calculus, partial-derivative

Let $n \geq 2$ and $k_i, \alpha_i \in \mathbb{R}_+$ for $i \in \{1, ..., n\}$

$$
G: \mathbb{R}_+^n \to \mathbb{R}, x \mapsto G(x) = \prod_{i=1}^n x_i^{\alpha_i} - \sum_{i=1}^n k_i x_i
$$
If $\sum_{i=1}^n \alpha_i > 1$,
show $G$ neither has a global nor a local extremum.

I don't have a clue on how to prove this. Can anyone help out?

Answer (score 0):

$G(x_1,...x_n)=\prod_{i=1}^n x_i^{\alpha_i} - \sum_{i=1}^n k_i x_i$, so $G_{x_j}=\alpha_jx_j^{\alpha_j-1}\prod_{i\ne j}x_i^{\alpha_i}-k_j$.

If G has a local extremum, then at the point where the extreme occurs, $G_{x_j}=0 \;\forall j$. Therefore $\alpha_jx_j^{\alpha_j-1}\prod_{i\ne j}x_i^{\alpha_i}=k_j$ or $G(x_1,...x_n)\alpha_j=k_jx_j$, which implies $G_{x_j}=\dfrac{k_j}{\alpha_j}$. Clearly, this expression is never 0, and hence G doesn't have a local extremum. Since G doesn't have a local extremum, it doesn't have a global extremum either. In fact, $G_{x_j}\gt 0 \; \forall j$ tells us that if we fix all the other variables and only let one variable, say $x_j$, vary, then the value of G will increase monotonically in $x_j$.

Comment: I think the step where you plug back in value of $G(x_1, ..., x_n)$ is wrong. I mean how can you substitute the value back and then again differentiate to get $G_{x_j} = \frac{k_j}{\alpha_j}$? Isn't it like saying $f(x, y) = (x^2+2x+5)y$, $f_y=(x^2+2x+5)=0$. Plug back in $f(x, y)$ to get $f(x, y)=0$. Hooray, $f_y=0$ we have found the minimum.

Incase, you are not satisfied, we need to use $\sum_{i=1}^n \alpha_i > 1$, else the result is not true. Here is the counter example https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=extrema+%28xy%29%5E%281%2F3%29+-0.5x+-0.5y&assumption=%22%5E%22+-%3E+%22Real%22

Comment: Can you show how we can use $\sum_{i=1}^n \alpha_i > 1$?

Comment: For instance  If G has a local extremum, then at the point where the extreme occurs, $G_{x_j}=0 \;\forall j$. Therefore, at this point, $x_j^{\alpha_j-1}=\dfrac{k_j}{\alpha_j\prod_{i\ne j}x_i^{\alpha_i}} \implies \prod_{j=1}^n x_j^{\alpha_j-1}=\prod_{j=1}^n\dfrac{k_j}{\alpha_j (x_j^{\alpha_j})^{n-1}}$. Hence,

$$\prod_{j=1}^n x_j^{n\alpha_j-1}=\prod_{j=1}^n\dfrac{k_j}{\alpha_j}\;\;\;\; (*)$$

Now, $G_{x_j}=0$ also implies $$\sum_{j=1}^nk_jx_j=(\sum_{j=1}^n\alpha_j)(\prod_{i=1}^n x_i^{\alpha_i})\gt \prod_{i=1}^n x_i^{\alpha_i}$$
which means $G\lt 0$ at the extremum.

Comment: Since $\sum_{i=1}^n \alpha_i\gt 1,\alpha_j>\dfrac 1n$ for some j. $(*)$ yields $nk_j\prod_{i\ne j} \dfrac{k_i}{\alpha_i}\gt \prod_{i=1}^n x_i^{n\alpha_i-1}\gt \prod_{i\ne j} x_i^{n\alpha_i-1}$